# How delete file from a custom file created in upload folder in custom wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom wp plugin with image upload section in front-end theme. user can upload image but how it can be removed from folder?

```php
if(isset($clicked_item_name)){
    chmod(CARSELL_UPLOAD_DIR_TEMP.$current_user_id, 0755); //this will get permission to file
    chmod($clicked_item_name, 0777);  //this will give permission to file. I this there is problem!?
    unlink($clicked_item_name);
}
```

Comment: print this `$clicked_item_name` and check whether it is getting the proper path to the image you are trying to remove?

Comment: @MominIqbal . Dear Momin. $clicked_item_name is a file name like test.jpg

Comment: `unlink(realpath($clicked_item_name ));` please try this. Hope this help

Comment: If it does not work, then please pass the relative path to the `$clicked_item_name` instead of only file name. Example: `c://xamp/htddocs/folder/images.jpg`

Comment: @MominIqbal the path to image is

/home/com12345/public_html/carsell/wpcontent/uploads/adv_img_temp_img/test.jpg
does the link correct?
it is on server

Comment: yes something like that. try to unlink with fixed/static path

Comment: @Mominlqbal rhank you very much. is there any way to use dynamic path? Tnx